# Magento1: VAT Validation using EU VIES service

Tags: validation, vat, magento-1.14, tax-calculation

Magento is using  EU VIES (VAT Information Exchange System) service to validate the VAT-IDs (http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl)

Is it reliable and how Magento is using it?

As VIES/Web team proposes following recommendation to ensure validation can be performed without blocking:

1. you perform `20k` or less requests for `VAT validations` per day,
2. you perform up to `5` validations to a `unique VAT number` per day,
3. you avoid performing blank or null or white space or corrupted or invalid (syntax, length) validations
4. you perform validations preferably until `10:00 am CET` and/or after `18:00 CET`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recieved confirmation from VIES-on-the-Web (VoW)

- The below are simply a proposal for you to follow;
- If you make proper use of the VoW you can make as many requests as you need. **There are no restrictions or limits either by means of volume or time of validation**;
- All conditions for using the VoW service are provided in the disclaimer at the corresponding page of the VoW: (Specific disclaimer for this service) http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/disclaimer.html
- You may also navigate through the remaining pages as well as the FAQ page of the VoW website for additional information